# What is >! in formatting?

Tags: discussion, markdown, spoilers

I've seen `>!` in the formatting. Which shows something only on hover. What is it? Why is it not documented.

Is there any other such unknown formattings that exist in SO editor?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, see [What’s the exact syntax for spoiler markup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup) for a description of the edge cases.

Comment: Check the [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) for all sort of editing experiments.

Comment: When you have a question about formatting, you should always first click on the "?" above the edit box, then "advanced help »", to get to [the markdown help page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to see if your question is answered there.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Some sites require this spoiler functionality — especially our sites that discuss plots and story lines (think [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/provide-a-markdown-extension-to-hide-text-anti-spoiler), [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and such sites).

It is a [custom markdown extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396) and it is documented on the [advanced editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers):

> To hide a certain piece of text and have it only be visible when a user moves the mouse over it, use the blockquote syntax with an additional exclamation point

Comment: [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) is also a huge place for this.

Comment: It's worth noting that one can also get to the advanced editing help page by clicking on the "?" above the edit box, then "advanced help »".

Answer (score 23):

It Markdown markup for a spoiler:

> You cannot see this until you mouse-over!

Move your mouse over the 'blank' block text to see what happens.

Not all sites really need this, but it is supported everywhere. Only sites that make regular use of it (such as SciFi and Movies) actually include the tag in [their documentation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).

> #### Spoilers
>
> To hide a certain piece of text and have it only be visible when a
> user moves the mouse over it, use the blockquote syntax with an
> additional exclamation point:
>
> ```
> At the end of episode five, it turns out that
>
> >! he's actually his father.
> ```

Comment: "he's actually his father." Spoiler alert, please!

Comment: @Beska But it is from Lords of the Rings

Comment: @hjpotter92: LotR episode 5 isn't out yet.  Did you get a leaked copy?

Comment: And Rosebud is his mother. :-)

Comment: Actually, spoiler formatting is documented in [Super User’s Help Center](http://superuser.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Comment: So? That just means the Super User mods feel it is a helpful syntax for their site.