# What stops the >! notation from working as a spoiler?

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

> A simple spoiler at the top of the question works, but the bug is that spoilers don't work further down the page.

I wanted to create a spoiler at the end of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26948159/563532), so I added the text in a spoiler block (based on the information in [What is `>!` in formatting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250894/what-is-in-formatting/250897#250897):

```
>! One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
>! imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
>! shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:

>! `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`
```

And the spoiler here is the same, not indented:

> ! One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
>   ! imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
>   ! shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:
>
> ! `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`

And, as you can see, the spoiler doesn't work.  That seems to be a bug.

---

#### Solution

Thanks [Madara Uchiha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha).  The solution is to ensure that even blank lines in the spoiler are prefixed with `>!`.

> One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
>  imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
>  shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:
>
>  `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`

```
>! One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
>! imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
>! shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:
>!
>! `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`
```

#### Residual bugs that still need fixing

The bug, then, is that the behaviour of spoiler text is not spelled out clearly in the documentation, nor in answers to other questions about spoilers that I've seen.  Also, the normal convention that 5 spaces after a leading `>` goes into `code mode` does not seem to work with spoilers.  That too should be mentioned (or, better, fixed).  Spoilers aren't just 'ordinary quoted blocks starting with `>!` instead of just `>`'; there are many differences, at least when you count them on the 'zero, one, many' scale.

Put succinctly, spoilers are still inadequately documented.

> It would be helpful if the advanced help in the Markdown help is complete enough to explain such pitfalls (or is it pratt-falls?).

Also:

> And I see that it is not deemed to be a bug but a support issue.  Hmmmm…

Comment: Well... works as designed == not a bug.

Comment: @Oded: WAD might be BIS == bug in specification, or it might be BID == bug in documentation.  Not having the system explain what the design is (crucial little details such as 'you cannot have two consecutive spoilers without intervening text' have not been documented before) means it is impossible for people to know whether they're hitting a bug or not.  And the fact that we can't tell from the help is a bug in the help.  And merely documenting it will mean 'documenting an unintuitive consequence of a design decision', but that doesn't make it a good design decision.

Comment: Why copy the answer to the contents of the *question*?

Comment: @BartoszKP: because I want to extend the information from the answer with assertions about the inadequacy of the documentation on the subject.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler All right, this however makes this a *chameleon question*. And the title no longer matches its purpose. Not a big problem, however looks a bit confusing :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: The question changed a bit once the answer gave a better understanding of the problem.  That's not unusual; when you don't know what the problem is, you can't necessarily describe the problem accurately. The problem becomes 'the functionality is more complex than the documentation says'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand this mechanism, it's not surprising to me and I know it happens :) The cause however, doesn't change the fact I've stated.

Comment: @Oded how can it really be working as intended if taking every `>` from a quote that renders in a single block and placing `!` after it *doesn't* make that entire block a spoiler block? If that really is what you intended it violates the principle of least surprise, and if I might be so bold a seemingly silly intention. Oooo, I said it. Silly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With spoilers, every line must begin with `>!`, including blank lines.

> One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
>  imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
>  shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:
>
>  `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`

```
>! One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
>! imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
>! shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:
>!  
>! `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`
```

Comment: Thanks!  That should be spelled out clearly in the Markdown help, though.

Comment: It should.​​​​​​

Comment: What keeps the renderer from interpreting the above broken example as two consecutive spoilers?

Comment: I have no idea. I've slaughtered a goat and currently drawing a circle to summon one of the devs.

Comment: Is it possible to have a formatted code block within a spoiler? Such that the code lines can retain their indentation?

Comment: @mbomb007 From experience, no. I may be wrong here though, it's worth asking a new question.

Comment: Asked here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287073/formatted-code-block-within-spoiler-tag