# Code in spoiler is unreadable, unless I click spoiler

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, spoilers

[Spoiler `>!`](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers) problem description:

1. At start `code` is shown with very dark background, which makes it hard to read.

[image]

2. When we click spoiler, code background will change to `standard one` but it will also prevent spoiler from fading out.

[image]

Example of problem on:

- Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825711/1393766 (bottom of the answer)
- and on Meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276894/1393766 which looks like this

  > One way to fix the problem — not necessarily the best, by any stretch of my
  >  imagination, but one which works — is to fix the the LHS of the `lhs << (15 - i)`
  >  shift so that it is either 0 or 1 that is shifted.  For example:
  >
  >  `((ptr[j] & (1 << (7 - i % 8))) ? 1 : 0) << (15 - i)`

If this click-able behaviour is desired and not bug (I am not sure which is it that is why I used [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tags mix), then could we at least change all backgrounds of code in spoiler to `standard one` so it would be more readable by default?

I am using newest version of ***Chrome (40.0.2214.111 m)*** and ***Windows 7 Ultimate*** (64-bit with service pack 1).

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature. You have to work extra hard to spoil the surprise. ;)

Comment: It appears that for some reason, the background color for the hover of the code tag within the spoiler class is set to #444, which is very dark. The reason clicking is fixing that is it is removing the spoiler class from the blockquote, thus removing the hover styling that is causing the dark background of the code. I'm seeing this on Chrome 40.0.2214.111 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced with Firefox 35.

Comment: @Kendra I added example in question. Also I decided to leave images just in case someone wouldn't be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Reproduced on Safari though: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqbdr.gif and on Firefox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wyD8H.gif

Comment: Ah! I have [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](http://stackapps.com/q/4486) installed, it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Meta posts: [On beta sites, the monospace formatting in a spoiler quote is evil.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136589) and [The CSS for spoilers is a mess. Let's fix it!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217779)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it seems that problem was [solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228441/186652) earlier, but returned with new SE look.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> `I pushed a fix for this to dev. The change will be live after our next production build.`