# Formatted code block within spoiler tag?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, spoilers

Is it possible to have a formatted code block within a spoiler `>!`? It would need to be such that the code lines can retain their indentation. I haven't been able to do it with anything except backticks `` ` ``.

So I can get close using backticks, and it's readable with a single line:

`` >! `print "Hello World"` ``

The result:

> `print "Hello World"`

But if using multiple lines, the tabbing is not formatted correctly, even with each line indented four spaces, like this:

`` >!    `if 1:`[2 spaces here for newline] ``
`` >!        `print "Hello World"` ``

The result:

> `if True:`
>         `print "Hello World"`

So is there a way to do multi-line code formatting within a spoiler? It'd be nice if I could do it without backticks, in a way such that prettify will still highlight the code by adding `<!-- language: lang-python -->` like this:

```python
if True:
    print "Hello World"
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: See [How can I put a whole code block in spoiler text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105735)

Comment: @Daedalus It happens all the time on the PCG site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's pretty close. So is there no way to get prettify at the same time?

Comment: @mbomb007: there is not, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why would you need to hide code? Don't make it harder to read or answer questions.

Comment: Why do you want it to look nice? your last assessment works and it is enough to give the user, the idea and again why do you want to hide the code It will make it harder to read questions

Comment: @Paulie_D It happens all the time on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com, where answers are not solutions to everyday problems or questions, but rather answers to a challenge that other users may desire to solve without seeing existing answers first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While I'm unclear how useful this would be, you can wrap the code in `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` blocks, such as:

```
>! <pre><code>if True:
>!     print "Hello World"</code></pre>
```

Which produces:

> ```python
> if True:
>      print "Hello World"
> ```

It will still pull syntax highlighting based on the question's tags or automatically, or even using the language-all hint, but you cannot apply a language hint manually to only this code block using this method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that.  Maybe I left the two spaces at the end of the line...  Anyway, it works.  Thanks!

Comment: When I try this, in the editor I get "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut."
Then, when I add 4 spaces everywhere the spoiler is gone

Comment: @BorisMulder I'm sorry you're having trouble with this, but as you can see in the answer, the formatting suggestion works. There is likely other text in your question which is causing the problem. Ask a new question if you cannot figure out a way of getting around the issue. Again, however, I wonder whether why you would need spoiler formatting on a site geared toward explaining questions and answers as clearly as possible...

Comment: thanks, I already figured it did not make sense in this case, I wanted to use a spoiler to append some log file to my post, but this is not the correct use case for spoilers. I used pastebin instead.
I guess a valid use case could be a programming puzzle where the answer is a piece of code.